# Verify Date format in any language (French, Chinese, Turkish)

Tags: python, date-format

I want to verify date format in any given format.
E.g. In French: `14-déc-2017`.
In normal English language `14-Dec-2017` is in `%d-%b-%Y` format. What I want is given date in any language format should be verified.

In python, below `datetime` function I'm using to verify date format in English.

```
datetime.strptime('14-Dec-2017', '%d-%b-%Y')
```

To verify date format in any other languages, which library/function is used?

Comment: Will you at least know the language? You can use locale aware checking.

Comment: How? In application, I want to verify. From drop-down, date format should be selected and after providing date in date field, date should be verified to confirm that provided date is in selected date format.

Comment: yes, but can you at least know whether OP is inputing the date in french? Or chinese?

Comment: No. I can provide date in any format, but eventually date will be converted in selected date format only. E.g. If I've selected date format is French and I provide date in 14-dec-2017, it will be displayed as 14-déc-2017.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need `locale` module:

```
import time
import locale

locales = ['fr', 'zh', 'tr'] # french, chinese, turkish

for loc in locales:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, loc)
    print(time.strftime("%d-%b-%Y"))

12-déc.-2017
12-12月-2017
12-Ara-2017
>>>
```

I tried that on Windows 10.

**Edit:** If you are on Ubuntu, run the `sudo locale-gen 'fr' 'zh' 'tr'` on your command line.

After that, try the code below:

```
import time
import locale

locales = ['fr_FR.utf-8', 'zh_CN.utf-8', 'tr_TR.utf-8'] # french, chinese, turkish

for loc in locales:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, loc)
    print(time.strftime("%d-%b-%Y"))

12-déc.-2017
12-12月-2017
12-Ara-2017
>>>
```

On the advice of @tripleee, I tried the above command and the Python code on Windows Subsystem for Linux and it ran as expected.

**Edit 2**: Maybe you need a function that takes a locale and a format and returns date in the format specified:

```
import time
import locale

def get_date_in(loc, df):
    formats = ["%d-%b-%Y", "%d %b %Y"]  # Update formats here

    for f in formats:
        if f == df:
            locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, loc)
            loc_date = time.strftime(f)
            return loc_date
```

Demo on Windows 10:

```
french = get_date_in('fr', "%d-%b-%Y")
chinese = get_date_in('zh', "%d %b %Y")
turkish = get_date_in('tr', "%d-%b-%Y")

print(french)
print(chinese)
print(turkish)

12-déc.-2017
12 12月 2017
12-Ara-2017
>>>
```

Demo on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
french = get_date_in('fr_FR.utf-8', "%d-%b-%Y")
chinese = get_date_in('zh_CN.utf-8', "%d %b %Y")
turkish = get_date_in('tr_TR.utf-8', "%d-%b-%Y")

print(french)
print(chinese)
print(turkish)

12-déc.-2017
12 12月 2017
12-Ara-2017
>>>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: @AnilBhatiya, try `locale.locale_alias` in your Python Shell.

Comment: If you are on Linux, you may need to reconfigure your locale settings.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 and the code is working fine for me with the output as shown.

Comment: It has to do with the locale settings of your OS, not Python.

Comment: Here I'm using below code.

locale.setlocale(category=locale.LC_ALL, locale="german")

It is working fine for English, Italian, German, Turkish languages. But for French, it is not. Throwing an error of 'unsupported locale settings'

Comment: If you are on Linux, please run `sudo locale-gen 'fr'` on your command line, then try the Python code with the locale set to French.

Comment: I'm working on windows 7. I tried every possible solution to make it work. but no luck. I appreciate your help @srig

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation of `%b` is locale-dependent.  To get a French interpretation, use a French locale.

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec 26 2015, 18:08:53)
>>> from locale import setlocale, LC_ALL
>>> setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.utf-8")
'fr_FR.utf-8'
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('12-déc-2017', '%d-%b-%Y')
datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 12, 0, 0)
```

Comment: On Linux you may need to run [`locale-gen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/locale-gen.8.html) for each locale which produces this error. It's not a Python problem specifically, but will obviously affect Python locale behavior. Other platforms will differ in the details, but probably have basically the same behavior.